# Gutenberg Blocks - Save a predefined text attribute?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to save an attribute for a custom Gutenberg block. Call it `contenttype`.

This attribute is already predefined - for instance, "discussion"

In my code, I figured this would be straightforward.

Here is my list of attributes:

```
    attributes: {

        selectedPost: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 0,
        },
        contenttitle: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
        contenttype: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'discussion',
        },
        blockId: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
    },
```

And here is where I set their values:

```
    onChangeSelectPost( value ) {
        // Find the post
        const post = this.state.posts.find( ( item ) => { return item.id == parseInt( value ) } );
        // Set the state
        this.setState( { selectedPost: parseInt( value ), post } );
        // Set the attributes
        this.props.setAttributes( {
            selectedPost: parseInt( value ),
            contenttitle: post.title.rendered,
            contenttype: 'discussion',
            blockId: this.props.clientId,
        });
    }
```

All is working fine, except that this `contenttype` just isn't showing up in the block's attributes. What I see in the database is

```
<!-- wp:cgb/block-my-block {"selectedPost":1071,"contenttitle":"Some Title","blockId":"8654cc3c-5k6d-47f4-8e22-97a0c3554567"} /-->
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

thanks

--- Update:
This seems to shed light on the problem:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7342

So now I have it working if I specify default so some arbitrary string, like "blah". Oddly enough, it was not working when I had `default:''`. Here is how I know specify the default:

```
        contenttype: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'discussion',
        },
```

And with the setAttributes call unchanged, that is

```
        this.props.setAttributes( {
            selectedPost: parseInt( value ),
            contenttitle: post.title.rendered,
            contenttype: 'discussion',
            blockId: this.props.clientId,
        });
```

all is working.

Comment: Have you set `contenttype` to its default value in the example you tested? Or did you change it? Why do you store the selectedPost in both local state _and_ the block attribute?

Comment: I thought if in the attributes I have `default: 'discussion'`, and in the setAttributes call I have `this.props.setAttributes( {
            selectedPost: parseInt( value ),
            contenttitle: post.title.rendered,
            contenttype: 'discussion',
            blockId: this.props.clientId,
        });`, that it guarantee things to work as desired, but figure I am missing something here.  I store selectedPost as an attribute because on front end I use that id in various ways.

Comment: Have it working now, updated above. Seems to be how Gutenberg works by design - came across this which is similar to my problem: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7342

Comment: My guess is that if the value matches the default value then iit won't explicitly save it because it wouldn't make a difference. As for selectedPost, I actually thought the state was superfluous, not the attribute